# Single line html or JSX tag to multiple lines - in sublime

Tags: html, jsx, sublimetext3, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to go from

```
<input value="123" type="text">
```

to

```
<input
  value="123"
  type="text"
>
```

in Sublime?

Comment: Why not use vs code it can do that I think

Comment: @ash because VSCode is bloated, slow, buggy, and not very attuned to the user community?